# how to deploy membership provider db to beanstalk

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

i have created a default MVC 4 app with web api. so far i have added a few API calls. 
i would like to use the out of the box membership provider with no customization.

on my local machines i have added two users and added two user roles.

in the api i have added [Authorize] attribute for the API calls class.

It works well and prevents calls to API if the user is not logged in.

However, when i deploy the app on to Amzaon Beanstalk the Register and Login functions are broken. I am getting

```
Error. An error occurred while processing your request.
```

in the web.config of the application i have:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-UserListsActionsTest-20131103214231;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-UserListsActionsTest-20131103214231.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Also, i have gone to the properties of the project and set "Items to deploy" to all files in this project.

should that not be enough? do i need to create a SQL db on beanstalk?

would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, I've used Amazons RDS service to create a SQL Server instance and point my connection string to that in which I'll run all of my Migrations to that database. That or you can point it to whatever SQL Server instance you have with the appropriate connection string.

You can then call update-database and have your Users / User Roles created in the `Seed()` method.

FYI: You may need to configure certain ports/permissions within the RDS instance to be friendly with the Elastic Beanstalk instance. (Think about security groups)

I would also download the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio as it'll help get you setup with the database connection string and the ability to publish straight to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: thank you. i am using the Toolkit already. i would think there is no reason to have to stand up an SQL instance if we push the mdf etc. over. i read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff361972(v=vs.100).aspx and it does not say anything about it either. i will set up an instance anywho and give it a try.

Comment: Well if you push the MDF over, is it being hosted on the server's SQL Server localdb instance?

Comment: no you are correct. it does not read from MDF. i went ahead and deployed MS SQL RDS, then use aspnet_regsql.exe, connected to AWS RDS from within the wizard and it created tables for me. then i updated the web.config.  that solved all the issues.

Comment: Ah: i found some interesting things.  1. if you update your default connection string to AWS RDS db and you deploy, then the framework creates the tables for your (the 6 you need not the all like aspnet_regsql.exe does).  your app then starts using them.  thus you dont need to create tables manually.  simply crate RDS, open ports, and deploy the project.  you may need to play around with the properties for package / sql section